# Adding an integer at the end of an input's name to get a specific url

Tags: php

I am trying to get a url where I can retrieve the selected values from.
For example, if I put a check mark on a and b then sumbit, I will get:

```
index.php?category=1&&category=2
```

I want to get this instead: index.php?**category0**=1&&**category1**=2
So that I can later get this specific value with $_GET['category0']

Is there a way to add a counter for the selected checkboxes and add 0,1,2,3.. at the end of the name of its input?

```
<form action="" method="get"> 

    <!-- this will be a php loop instead of hardcored 
         which will retrieve data from the db -->

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1">a</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="2">b</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="3">c</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="4">d</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category" value="5">e</label>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Using a for loop? Seems you already knew the answer, did you try it?

Comment: yeah but just adding 0, 1, 2 at the end of each name isn't what I want as I don't know what could be clicked right.. if you click d and e, then d should be category0 and e should be category1

Comment: This is a set of checkboxs, not a set of radio buttons.  Therefore, give each checkbox a unique name..  The checkboxs that are not checked will not be sent to the server, so, for post, if(isset($_POST['category1']) ) then the checkbox named category1 is checked, if the $_POST['category1'] is not set, then the checkbox is not checked.  I.E. give each checkbox a unique name.

Answer (score 1):

Category variables are overwriting each other, try this instead:

```
<form action="" method="get"> 

    <!-- this will be a php loop instead of hardcored 
         which will retrieve data from the db -->

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1">a</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2">b</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="3">c</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4">d</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="5">e</label>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Or even:

```
<form action="" method="get"> 

    <!-- this will be a php loop instead of hardcored 
         which will retrieve data from the db -->

    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[a]" value="1">a</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[b]" value="2">b</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[c]" value="3">c</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[d]" value="4">d</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="category[e]" value="5">e</label>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then you can get the info this way:

```
$_GET['category']['a']
```

Comment: i thought of that, this returns the array. so if i selected a and b, i get 12 (which is category 1 and category 2), but how can i pass this into my query to display results where category0=1 and category1=2

Comment: Why don't you handle this by doing a foreach on `$_GET['category']` in your response script ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="category'.$i.'" value="'.$i.'">a</label>';
```

It depends a bit on what you want to do with the data (you might need to adjust the 'a' label text in this example to your needs), there are usually several ways of passing data that all work, but require different levels of effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an HTML question, than a PHP question, since regardless of what technology your server uses, the browser will send the information consistently. When submitting a form, the browser uses the name and value attributes of the `<form>` element's inputs. To receieve the parameters as you said, change your name and value attributes to the following:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="category0" value="1">a</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="category1" value="2">b</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="category2" value="3">c</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="category3" value="4">d</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="category4" value="5">e</label>
```

EDIT: On the server side, you could do the following to generate the above markup:

```
$category_names = array("a", "b", "c");
for ($i=0;$i<count($category_names);$i++) {
  echo '<label><input type="checkbox" name="category'.$i.'" value="'.$i+1.'">'.$category_names[$i].'</label>';
}
```

Comment: this is hard coding it. i don't want it that way

Comment: See my edit, if your form is generated by PHP code, then you have to generate it using a loop. Then you can just add more categories into an array, and have it automatically populate (or presumably, you're getting them from a database or other data source).